# How do i ensure that Email Sent gets passed to the right Row after a Verification Process

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So i have 3 functions

1. function afterFormSubmit(e)
   This receives function calls & generates PDF upon submission
2. function sendMail_Verification()
   This sends the email out for the submission to be verified
3. function sendMail()
   This sends out the email to respondent with the generated PDF

**Current Problem**

1. I cant seem to generate the pdf after Approving perhaps cos of the (e) @afterFormSubmit, so currently generates upon submission.
2. When i have 2 entries from respondents, and i am to verfiy each one, the SendMail() function has an **if statement** to check if the first Respondent submission has been **Approved on Column 8** and then triggers the email. **However**, **it sends the Email to both first Respondent & second respondent even though second respondent has no Approve on its row**
   Using this  ws.getRange(2,12,ws.getLastRow()-1,1).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); to pass the **Email_Sent**

Any suggestions is very much appreciated

Below is the code

```
 var Approve = 'Approve';

 var Reject = 'Reject';

 var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

function afterFormSubmit(e){
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("People");
var su = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 9).getValue();
var ku = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 9).getValue();
var check = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 8).getValue();
if(su == ""){
  var check = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 8).getValue();
  var checke = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 11).getValue();
  var checkv = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 12).getValue();

  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();

  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("People");
  ws.getRange(entryRow, 9).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
  ws.getRange(entryRow, 10).setValue(pdfFile.getName());
  }
  if(check == "" && checke != EMAIL_SENT){
  assignEditUrls();
  sendMail_Verification();
  }
  if(su == ku){
  sendMail();
 }
 sendMail_Rejection();
}


function sendMail_Verification(){
var A = 0;var B = 1;
var C = 2;var D = 3;
var E = 4;var F = 5;
var G = 6;var H = 7;
var I = 8; var J = 9; 
var e_mail_x = "##";
var K = 10; 
var L = 11; 
var M = 12;
var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("verification_Email");
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("People");
var lr = ws.getLastRow();
var data = ws.getRange("A2:M" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
data = data.filter(function(r){return r[10] != EMAIL_SENT});
data.forEach(function(row){
emailTemp.A = row[A];
emailTemp.B = row[B];
emailTemp.C = row[C]; 
emailTemp.D = row[D];
emailTemp.F = row[F];
emailTemp.G = row[G];
emailTemp.H = row[H];
emailTemp.I = row[I];
emailTemp.J = row[J];
emailTemp.K = row[K];
emailTemp.L = row[L];
emailTemp.M = row[M];

var hmtlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
var name = "###";
var subject = "Verification for " + row[D] + " - "+ row[A];

GmailApp.sendEmail(
    e_mail_x,
    subject, 
    "Your email doesnt support HTML",
    //Passing objects
    {name: name, htmlBody: hmtlMessage}
    
  );
  
});
ws.getRange(2,11,ws.getLastRow()-1,1).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
 }


 function sendMail(){
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("People");
 var lr = ss.getLastRow();
 var su = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 9).getValue();
 var ku = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 9).getValue();
 var check = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 8).getValue();
 var checkv = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 12).getValue();
 if(check == Approve && checkv != EMAIL_SENT){
   var A = 0;var B = 1;
   var C = 2;var D = 3;
   var E = 4;var F = 5;
   var G = 6;var H = 7;
   var I = 8; var J = 9;
   var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
   var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("People");
   var lr = ws.getLastRow();
   var data = ws.getRange("A2:L" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
   data.forEach(function(row){
   emailTemp.A = row[A];
   emailTemp.B = row[B];
   emailTemp.C = row[C]; 
   emailTemp.D = row[D];
   emailTemp.F = row[F];
   emailTemp.G = row[G];
   emailTemp.H = row[H];
   emailTemp.I = row[I];
  
   var hmtlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
   var name = "###";
   var subject = "Submission for " + row[D] + " - "+ row[A];
  
   GmailApp.sendEmail(
   row[E],
   subject, 
    "Your email doesnt support HTML",
    //Passing objects
    {name: name, htmlBody: hmtlMessage, /*attachments: [pdfFile]*/}
  );
});
 ws.getRange(2,12,ws.getLastRow()-1,1).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
 } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to work, i placed the GmailApp.sendEmail() outside the callback function and used the entryRow to set the value at the active row.

```
)};
var subA = ss.getRange(entryRow, 1).getValue();
var subD = ss.getRange(entryRow, 4).getValue();
var hmtlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
var name = "###";
var subject = "### Verification for " + subD + " - "+ subA;

GmailApp.sendEmail(
    e_mail_x,
    subject, 
    "Your email doesnt support HTML",
    {name: name, htmlBody: hmtlMessage}
  );

ss.getRange(entryRow, 11).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a 'listener' for 'approve' submit and move generate pdf function there

```js
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  /* ... */

  /* Check whether it is 'approve' submit */
  // const user = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  const responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  const o = {};
  for (const response of responses){
    const question = response.getItem().getTitle();
    const answer = response.getResponse();
    o[question] = answer;
  }
  if (o['Password Question Title'] == 'PASSWORD') {
    if (o['Approve Question Title'] == Approve) {
      /* generated PDF */
    }
  }
}
```

2. Please correct your condition

```
var su = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 9).getValue();
var ku = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()-1, 9).getValue();

  if(su == ku){
  sendMail();
 }
```

---

```
function afterFormSubmit(e){

      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("People");
      var su = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 9).getValue();
      var ku = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 9).getValue();
      var check = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 8).getValue();
      var checke = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 11).getValue();
      var checkv = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 12).getValue();
      const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
      const responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
      if(su == ""){
       const o = {};
        for (const response of responses){
          const question = response.getItem().getTitle();
          const answer = response.getResponse();
          o[question] = answer;
        }
       if (o['Decision'] == Approve) {
      /* generated PDF */
      const info = e.namedValues;
      const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
      const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
      const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("People");
      ws.getRange(entryRow, 9).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
      ws.getRange(entryRow, 10).setValue(pdfFile.getName());
      } 
    }
     if(check == "" && checke != EMAIL_SENT){
       assignEditUrls();
       sendMail_Verification();
     }
       if(check == Approve && checkv != EMAIL_SENT){
        if(su == ku){
          sendMail();
         //ss.getRange(activeRow,12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        }
       }
/* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks.. How do you mean modify the url in sendMail_Verification()

Comment: `sendMail_Verification()` is different from 'approve'? I though you send a link and approve upon click.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Oh no. What i do is, i use the assignEditUrls(); to email out the edit link to the admin to approve.. its all done on the same form. Is there an example on how to perform approval based on link clicked in email?

Comment: Do you mean sendMail_Verification() is sent to admin, and the steps are: i) open form with edit link ii) check the form iii) approve(update the spreadsheet cell)?

Comment: i) open form with edit link 
ii) check the form
iii) approve on the form (as there is a set password to access Admin section on the same form) which then updates the sheet.

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: Thanks. Is the above example using webapps? Cos my scenario is on Google Forms.

Comment: Modified. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235505/discussion-between-king-michael-king-and-idfurw).